# T-SQL Aggregating rows

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

**Table structure I'm working with:**
BoM table (What product are required to make the finished product):
Here is the @BomList table

```
╔══════════════╦═════════════╦══════════════╗
║ ParentPartId ║ ChildPartId ║ ChildPartQty ║
╠══════════════╬═════════════╬══════════════╣
║ MCD1         ║  2000416027 ║            2 ║
║ MCD1         ║  2000316029 ║            1 ║
║ MCD1         ║  2001020022 ║            1 ║
╚══════════════╩═════════════╩══════════════╝
```

Work Order table (What needs to be created):

```
╔═════════════╦═════════════════╦══════════════╗
║ WorkOrderId ║ WorkOrderItemId ║ ParentPartId ║
╠═════════════╬═════════════════╬══════════════╣
║        1234 ║            6735 ║ MCD1         ║
╚═════════════╩═════════════════╩══════════════╝
```

How many are actually made for a order.
Here is the cutdown version of t_WorkCenterRouting table.

```
╔═════════════════╦═════════════╦═════╗
║ WorkOrderItemId ║ ChildPartId ║ Qty ║
╠═════════════════╬═════════════╬═════╣
║            6735 ║  2000316029 ║   1 ║
║            6735 ║  2001020022 ║   1 ║
║            6736 ║  2000416027 ║  10 ║
║            6736 ║  2000316029 ║   3 ║
║            6736 ║  2001020022 ║   3 ║
║            6737 ║  2000416027 ║   1 ║
║            6737 ║  2000316029 ║   1 ║
║            6737 ║  2001020022 ║   1 ║
╚═════════════════╩═════════════╩═════╝
```

**The output I am looking for**
So from the above table we can see that WorkOrderItem 6735 can not make the full product as it's missing 2000416027 x2. So, I don't want these to be shown.

We can also see WorkOrderItem 6737 is can not make the full product as it's missing 2000416027 x1. So, I don't want these to be shown.

We can also see WorkOrderItem 6736 can make a total of x3 products.

I would like to see the total amount of makable products per work order item.
So, the query would show:

```
╔═════════════════╦═════╗
║ WorkOrderItemId ║ Qty ║
╠═════════════════╬═════╣
║            6737 ║   3 ║
╚═════════════════╩═════╝
```

The query I have tried so far:

```
SELECT twcr.WorkOrderItemId, 
        bl.ChildPartQty, 
        SUM( ISNULL( twcr.Qty, 0 ) ) / bl.ChildPartQty AS 'TotalQty'
FROM @BomList bl
LEFT JOIN niko.t_WorkCenterRouting twcr ON twcr.ChildCode = bl.ChildPartId AND twcr.WorkCenterId = 4
WHERE (twcr.WorkCenterRoutingId IS NULL OR twcr.ParentCode = @ProductCode)
GROUP BY twcr.WorkOrderItemId, twcr.ChildCode, bl.ChildPartQty
```

Problem is if we look at work order item id 6735 doesn't have the product 2000416027 in there. So, I can't match the work order item to get the minimum value qty.

If this question is unclear or missing any information let me know. Thank you.

....................

**My ugly solution**

```
    SELECT wcr.WorkOrderItemId,
                ( SELECT TOP 1 ROUND( SUM( ISNULL( twcr.Qty, 0 ) / bl.ChildPartQty ), 0, 1 )
                                        FROM #BomList bl
                                        LEFT JOIN niko.t_WorkCenterRouting twcr ON twcr.ChildCode = bl.ChildPartId AND twcr.WorkCenterId = 4 AND twcr.ParentCode = @WorkOrderCode AND  wcr.WorkOrderItemId = twcr.WorkOrderItemId
                                        GROUP BY twcr.WorkOrderItemId, bl.ChildPartId, bl.ChildPartQty
                                        ORDER BY SUM( ISNULL( twcr.Qty, 0 ) / bl.ChildPartQty ) ) AS 'Qty'
    FROM niko.t_WorkCenterRouting wcr
    WHERE wcr.WorkOrderItemId IN ( SELECT twcr.WorkOrderItemId
                                    FROM #BomList bl
                                    LEFT JOIN niko.t_WorkCenterRouting twcr ON twcr.ChildCode = bl.ChildPartId AND twcr.WorkCenterId = 4 AND twcr.ParentCode = @WorkOrderCode
                                    WHERE (twcr.WorkCenterRoutingId IS NULL OR twcr.ParentCode = @WorkOrderCode )
                                    GROUP BY twcr.WorkOrderItemId, bl.ChildPartId, bl.ChildPartQty ) AND
                ( SELECT TOP 1 SUM( ISNULL( twcr.Qty, 0 ) / bl.ChildPartQty )
                        FROM #BomList bl
                        LEFT JOIN niko.t_WorkCenterRouting twcr ON twcr.ChildCode = bl.ChildPartId AND twcr.WorkCenterId = 4 AND twcr.ParentCode = @WorkOrderCode
                        GROUP BY twcr.WorkOrderItemId, bl.ChildPartId, bl.ChildPartQty
                        ORDER BY SUM( ISNULL( twcr.Qty, 0 ) / bl.ChildPartQty ) ) >= 1
    GROUP BY wcr.WorkOrderItemId
```

Thank you for your input people. I'm sorry my question wasn't well explained it's just complexity of all tables and many business logic in there. As it's data-shapping of many different tables to get to this end goal.

- WorkOrder
- WorkOrderItem
- t_WorkCenterRouting
- t_WorkCenterProductRoute
- Product
- ProductFF
- BoM

Comment: 1. where or how do we know what "the finished product" is? (lines 1 & 2 of question)

Comment: 2. "So from the above table we can see ..." only after I read the statements, I'm missing something, HOW would we determine that certain parts are missing?

Comment: I tried simplifying the question as this contains many tables which would take a lot of explaining. The finished product is passed to stored procedure which then uses CTE recursive to get all products which make that finished product. So, it's a simple variable I can use to get the finished product but that's not that problem. The real problem is like you said in your 2nd comment. How would we determine part which are missing. If needs be I can expand my question with more of the tables in use but I don't want to question to get that complexed that no one will read it.

Comment: What part of this data is telling me that Work Order Item `6735` and `2000416027` are in any way related - I can't see anything anywhere where any kind of hierarchy is represented, nor any place where those two IDs appear in the same row.

Comment: Sorry, I've edited my question. Hope that clears a few things up. Thank you for your patience with me. :)

Answer (score 0):

Hope the following `SELECT` may help you:

```
SELECT two.WorkOrderItemId, MIN(COALESCE(twcr.Qty/b.ChildPartQty, 0)) as N
FROM t_WorkOrder two
INNER JOIN BOM b on b.ParentpartId = two.ParentPartId
LEFT JOIN t_WorkCenterRouting twcr ON b.ChildPartId = twcr.ChildPartId AND two.WorkOrderItemId = twcr.workOrderItemId
GROUP BY two.WorkOrderItemId
HAVING MIN(COALESCE(twcr.Qty/b.ChildPartQty, 0)) > 0
ORDER BY two.WorkOrderItemId
```

Comment: Thanks for your input I should of said the t_WorkCenterRouting isn't summed up. I'm going to stick with my ugly solution until I have my free time to attempt a better readable and manageable.